# How to turn off console.log() for production in Cordova / PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, debugging, cordova, mobile

How can I turn off the JavaScipt console.log() for production in Cordova / PhoneGap? Disabling the debugging information in the console probably speeds up the mobile app quite a bit.

There are numerous approaches, but none seems to work.

- overriding console.log - e.g., [Override console.log(); for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production)
- Override Cordova DebugConsole.prototype.log - e.g., http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/quiet-the-console-phonegap-ios/

Any working examples? Other feasible approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping might be a solution. If no 3rd party library is using the actual console and if you only want to use the log method.

```
var konsole = {
    log: function () {
        if (env === 'dev') {
            console.log(arguments)
        }

    }
}

konsole.log('fff');
```

env is a replacement for an environment var, which you could get from some kind of registry.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is to override the `Debug Console` plugin which on iOS defaults to `CDVDebugConsole`. Subclass that class then do something like this:

```
- (void)log:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        [super log:command];
    #endif
}
```

Remember to update your `config.xml` to use the new plugin.

Comment: "Don't remember" - I guess you mean either "remember" or "don't forget"?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using: https://github.com/sunnykgupta/jsLogger

Features:

- It safely overrides the console.log. Takes care if the console is not available (oh yes, you need to factor that too.)
- Stores all logs (even if they are suppressed) for later retrieval.
- Handles major console functions like log, warn, error, info.
- Is open for modifications and will be updated whenever new suggestions come up.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the plugin.