# Grab chrome console message and use in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome-console

I made Asp.Net web page with `<iframe>`

```
 <body>
   <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
 </body>
```

When i inspect that page in Chrome, i recive some message in console [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4YX.png)

I need grab that message and when find specific text do some staff in my web page.

Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible if page inside IFrame is on different domain.

If page inside IFrame is on the same domain as parent page you may try to capture messages send to console by [overriding `console.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production)  inside IFrame with JavaScript on parent page.

You may want to read on ["same origin policy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) to have better idea what should/should not be possible in a browser.