# Prevent warn message in browser console javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I'm developing using ionic framework, and often I see this warn:

[image]

Text version:

> A DOM event generated from JavaScript has triggered a default action inside the browser. This behavior is non-standard and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 for more details.

I tried this code to avoid the above warn:

```
fnWarn = console.warn;
console.warn = function() {
    if (/A DOM event generated from JavaScript/i.test(arguments[0])) {
        return false;
    }
    fnWarn.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

But the warn still shows up.

Is there any way to hide it?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? It's just a warning.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I think he wants to avoid the warning

Comment: @JaromandaX: See the quoted code. That's not trying to address the source of the issue, it's just trying to hide it.

Comment: @Guedes, Check out the answer in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production

Comment: @Guedes, In addition to my previous comment, I hope you will see this warnings only during your development phase, In production they won't appear

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - true dat - I read the word "avoid" and didn't think to read the code :p

Comment: @DavidR: Internally-generated warnings don't necessarily go through that object.

Comment: @DavidR: *"In production they won't appear"* They will for anyone who opens dev tools, which users of the production site can do.

Comment: I guess he'll have to wait until Chrome 53 ... oh, wait, that's the current version of Chrome - guess they haven't figured out how to do it yet - no wait, that link takes you to a page that states this wont happen in Chrome 53

Comment: Could be an older version Ionic. Also the solution of `var console = {}; console.log = function(){};` should include `console.warn` otherwise throws error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and Jaromanda, I meant production build of "Ionic", I'm not talking about canary vs production of google chrome.

Comment: @DavidR I wasn't referring to your comments at all - the issue is a warning that some behaviour in chrome is going to change ... since all other browsers behave "properly", then I can't see why, when Chrome is in line with other browsers, this will be an issue at all ... OP - what version of chrome are you running?

Comment: I've tried now: `var val = arguments[0]; debugger;` in the first line of my function. The warn showed up without stopping, I'm confuse

Comment: @DavidR: Ah, yes, this is Ionic; if end users are using it in Cordova/PhoneGap, then quite true, they won't see the message.

Comment: @Guedes - version of chrome you are running - this shouldn't happen in chrome 53 if I'm reading that link correctly

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry!

Comment: @JaromandaX. My chrome version is 52.0.2743.116. I'm updating it right now :)

Comment: current is 53 ... update and your problem may (should) vanish

Comment: OMG!! The warn disappeared, but my selects stopped working!! How can I downgrade the chrome?

Answer (score 0):

David R linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production) in his comment which redefines `console`, so really kudos should go to him. This should help but isn't advisable to do:

```
var console = {};
console.log = function(){};
console.warn = function(){};
console.info = function(){};
console.error = function(){};
```

If using this method you should also include:

```
window.console = console;
```

to cover browsers that don't support `console`

It should be noted that when using bundler or similar to package your app they have the option to remove logs, warnings etc if my memory serves. If you're not packaging stuff up yourself then you could use the min version of Ionic it should exclude logs, warnings, info etc.

Also it doesn't appear to have that message in the latest version of [ionic](http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.js)