# console.log line number in debugger

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I'm looking for a simple way to make a log function.

I'm calling a function `logSuc("return from Prom")`, the function is on line 30.

So the code  will always point to the line 30 of that function. In the console:

[image: console]

So say have this code:

```
const logSuc = (msg) => {
   console.log(`%c ${msg}`, 'background: green; color: white; display: block;'); 
};
```

An alternative could be:

```
const log = console.log;
function red(msg) {
  return `%c ${msg}`, 'background: red; color: white; display: block;';
}
log(red('its red');
```

But now i have two functions and I want to keep it short and simple

So the problem is my `logSuc("")` **always points to line 30**.

But I want it to be point to the **line where I call logSuc("that worked")**.

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: Override `console.log` function [Override console.log(); for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production)

Comment: Hopefully more clear now. I didn't find the awnser in Justinas Q: Overwr....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you get from using `Function.prototype.bind` on `console.log` will point to the line number where it’s called. It’s a bit limited, but if you only ever want to pass it one string argument, it’ll work:

```
const logSuc = console.log.bind(console, '%c %s',
    'background: green; color: white');
```

Tested in both Firefox and Chrome.

For more complex behaviour, you can manually blackbox the script containing the logging function, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35516589/707111) for Chrome and by activating the “blackbox” button on a script in the debugger in Firefox (beside `{} Pretty print source`, an eye icon).

Comment: Perfect. I will buy you a beer if I ever met you :D
https://jsfiddle.net/4404LhhL/3/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Builtins being blackboxed by default would be my first guess.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you replace `console.log` by `console.trace`. That way you see where the call comes from, thus solving your problem.

Comment: Is there a way we can get the output of console.trace in a variable?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can only get the stack information with errors. How about: var s = new Error().stack