# Include console..log statements only conditionally and remove them from production distribution of javascript file

Tags: javascript

I've got `console.log` statements all over the place in my JavaScript source files printing stuff out to the console that I don't want the user to see.

One way is to scan through all my JavaScript source files and remove the console.log statements.

But I was wondering if there was a way to have them in there but not execute them for production distributions. Is there a way to conditionally include them (or whatever you want) akin to C/C++/C# debug symbols?

```
#if DEBUG
  console.log("User IP Address: " + localStorage.getItem("userIP"));
#endif
```

I understand there's no way to distinguish between a production distro and a development one, and there are no binary symbols since there's no compilation of JavaScript to object files, but if the language were to include a special construct like `#if <SYMBOL>` with some pre-defined symbols, that would make life easier?

Comment: Check next: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production

Comment: which enviornment you work?

Comment: @Shidersz: Oh, yes. Why didn't I think of this hack? :-) Thanks.

Comment: @tvankith I am working client-side on the browser.

Comment: if you npm then you can use babel-plugin-transform-remove-console https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console

Comment: did you get the solution

Comment: @tvankith Presently in the middle of debugging. Will come back in a day or so and tell you what I did.