# When I override console.log, how can I export it to other files?

Tags: javascript, module.exports

I have a main.ts and a helper.ts. In the helper.js I tried to override console.log and export it so I could use the code in my main.js, but when I run a console.log() it crashes with the error below. I was trying to adapt this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30197438/1634753). What am I missing here?

I am transpiling Typescript files to JS using `ts-node main.ts`

Error in main.ts:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

I tried to fix this by adding at the bottom of helper.ts: `(this as any).window.console = console;` but got the same error.

helper.ts

```
export var console = (function(oldCons) {
  return {
    log: function(text: any) {
      oldCons.log("WHEEE" + text);
      // Your code
    },
    info: function(text: any) {
      oldCons.info(text);
      // Your code
    },
    warn: function(text: any) {
      oldCons.warn(text);
      // Your code
    },
    error: function(text: any) {
      oldCons.error(text);
      // Your code
    }
  };
})(window.console);
```

main.ts

```
import {console} from './helper.ts'
console.log("hi stack overflow")
```

Comment: Is that all the code in the file? Can you show how this is imported and used in your other code?

Comment: Do you have to do this way? If you override the `window.console` directly, it will work.

Comment: The stack trace says it's a typescript file. What did this get transpiled into?

Comment: @Bergi sorry about that. Added info that Im transpiling using ts-node

Comment: Where are you running this? `window` is available only in a browser. If you're running in Node environment just remove `window.console` and use `global.console`.

Comment: @Rilcon42 Wait, `ts-node`? Is this not a frontend script?

Comment: @Rilcon42 There is no `window` in node.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this in my app, but to register a log in a separate file:

```
console.log = function(d) {     

try {
        var timestamp = '\n[' + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString() + '] '
        log_file.write(util.format(timestamp + d))
        log_stdout.write(util.format(timestamp + d))
    } catch(e) {
        return
    }
}

var log_file    = fs.createWriteStream('log/'+ new Date().getDate() +'-'+ (new Date().getMonth()+1) +'-'+ new Date().getFullYear() +'.log', { encoding: 'utf-8', flags: 'a+' })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the global object across environments, use `globalThis`. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

That said, I wouldn't recommend replacing accessing global objects. It'll just lead to misery down the road.