# JavaScript: Trigger event when value is logged to the console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm working with some blackbox minified/obscured javascript that runs `console.log('hoyo')` when it's ready for action.

I'd like to trigger an event when that value is logged to the console (I know this is bootleg). Is it possible to do so? Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is overriding `console.log` a possibility?
Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production):

```
var og = console.log;

console.log = function(arg) {
  if (arg == 'heyo') alert('send the missles!');
  og(arg);
}
```

ps. not enough rep to post it as a comment...

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that. I'll accept this as soon as SO lets me. Thanks for this simple solution!