# Collect JavaScript console messages in App Insights

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

JavaScript [console object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) provides many ways to output messages to a browser console:

```
console.log
console.error
console.warn
console.info
console.trace
```

By default Application Insights does not send console messages as telemetry to Azure Portal ([Sending telemetry to the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#sending-telemetry-to-the-azure-portal)) so my question is: What are the ways to capture console messages as telemetry in Application Insights?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is probable going to be to override the console functions themselves. There is an existing answer that describes how to do this: [Override console.log(); for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production/30197438#30197438)

Keep in mind, that with custom implementation for App Insights, you'll usually want to use an [npm installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#npm-based-setup) instead of the App Insights code snippet to setup App Insights.

The result might look like something like this:

```
// define a new console
var console=(function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            oldCons.log(text);
            telemetry.TrackTrace(text, SeverityLevel.Warning);
        },
        //override other console methods
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just wanted to mention that the second link you provided does not work.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. I've fixed the broken link