# How to remove all line breaks from a Node JS application console log call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging

I am working in a NodeJS app built using Express.

Logs from several files, and from libraries log fine, but many of them, including from libraries I have no control, have some sort of line break in them.

My goal is to have a single line of logging without the line breaks.

for example:

```
var a = 'var a';
var b = 'var b';
var c = 'var c';

console.log({ a, b, c });
```

Instead of seeing those in separate lines I would like to have them in a single line.

Is it possible to somehow intercept globally the call, and remove all line breaks?

Could I do that in logstash, or some other facility?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production

Answer (score 0):

The [core util module](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) has `util.format` that can do the job, if the data is simple enough.

```
const util = require('util');

var a = 'var a';
var b = 'var b';
var c = 'var c';

console.log({ a, b, c });

console.log(util.format(a, b, c));
```